# How can I edit this code to set one part of my code to be different on this website on mobile?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, wordpress-gutenberg

I've tried a few things but I'm not really sure what I'm doing in regards to the code.

So I'm using the twenty twenty one theme with the overlapping image feature to make the image in the right column slightly hang over the text in the left column, but I wanted the sign up form further under the image so extended the width to 120%. I love how it looks on desktop but on mobile it extends beyond the bound of the website and creates a horizontal scroll and I want it to not do that and to look just as good on mobile.

You can see here: http://thepositivity-co.stackstaging.com

I'm not sure the best way to edit the code so it fits and looks normal/good on mobile as well as having the overlap I like on desktop. I really would appreciate any help. Here's the code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/2QPOwGp6

(it was too many characters to put here)

Thank you!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. We will not go to other websites and they will change over time, making this question useless for future visitors

Comment: Also read [Something in my web site doesn't work can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @mplungjan the code is too many characters to post here though?

Comment: We want a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan gotcha thanks

Comment: Looking at your code it is not fixable after the fact. Instead you need a [template that supports mobiles.](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+templates+free+responsive+mobile+friendly)